# wp_enqueue_style on template_redirect level?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head, template-redirect

I am using the following function, which works fine, in order to provide a minimal output of HTML at a WordPress installation of mine:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test' );

function test()
{ 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo home_url() ?>/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/style.css'>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    exit();
}
```

It does exactly what I want, but I'm considering of loading my style the proper way, using `wp_enqueue_style`.

Since im not loading `wp_head`, I tried it and it seems not possible on `template_redirect level`.

Is there any way to enqueue my style on my function without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use `wp_enqueue_style` is to allow WordPress to manage dependencies between stylesheets. Since you're only outputting a barebones page here, there really is no point to use it.

That said, if you look at the [hook order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), you see that `template_redirect` is actually called quite late in the process, just before the scripts and styles are enqueued, but before `wp_head`. As you can see in the [list of default filters/actions](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php) (and as you found out) the scripts and styles are only printed at the `wp_head` stage, with this line of code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_styles', 8 );
```

So, if you want to enqueue a file at the `template_redirect` stage you will have to cheat by running both the enqueueing and printing process early. That is not too difficult, though, because WordPress has already been fully loaded at this stage. All functions are available, including the [styles class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Styles). In stead of your line `<link rel = ... >` you could execute the styles chain of command early, like this:

```
wp_styles (); // initialize the styles object
wp_enqueue_style ('my_handle', 'path-to-file'); // make the file ready for printing
wp_print_styles (); // print the enqueued style
```

I didn't test this, because it doesn't really make sense, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. wp_styles works, however, it brings the emoji's style aswell in my head ( https://pastebin.com/J2inxNDt ) . Any ideas on how to exlude it?

Comment: remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );  seems to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: glad it worked for you